# Adding a function in helpers.php to count expenses. PHP , Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a function which will calculate the expenses made to a specific project.

Model Expense belongs to Project and User

```
  protected $fillable=[

        'name','payment_method','currency','value','date','description','user_id','project_id',
];
public function project(){

    return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);

}

public function user(){

    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);

}
```

and Project has Many Users and Expenses

```
   protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'description', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'value', 'client_id','currency','',
    ];
public function expenses(){

    return $this->hasMany(Expense::class);

}

public function users(){ //was user before

    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,"user_projects");
}
```

Function in helpers.php is this

```
function expenses_per_project(){
//dont understand how to do this. so sry.

}
```

when user adds an expense it is like this:
[expense add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNTnX.png)

expenses Dashboard is this:
[Expenses Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4h59.png)

I am failing to understand how to do the function, so a bit of help would be more than welcome!

Also, every project has belongs to many users, and the expense is determined by their wage too.

```
public function wages(){

    return $this->hasMany(UserWage::class,'user_id');

}
public function projects(){

    return $this->hasMany(Project::class);
}
```

Comment: do you have access to the project object whose expenses you want?

Comment: yes I do,  should I post code of that too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this, I'm not sure what columns your Expense model has, but you need to put the name of the column that holds the expense's value as the parameter for the sum function.

```
function expenses_per_project($id) {
    $project = Project::find($id);
    return (float) $project->expenses()->sum('value_column');
}
```

And an extra snippet, project expenses per user

```
function expenses_per_project_and_user($project_id, $user_id) {
    $project = Project::find($project_id);
    return (float) $project->expenses()->where('user_id', $user_id)->sum('value_column');
}
```

Comment: should I add expenses_per_project_and_user in helpers too?

Comment: no you don't need to, I wrote it as an extra if you might need to sum expenses per project and user at some point in the future :)

Comment: thats what I wanted to do, project expenses is calculated when from the expenses they made, and - the wage of the users that work for that. but Im not sure if I added it